# react-simple-typewriter: Loop does not work

Tags: reactjs, loops

I DID NOT GET THE DESIRED OUTPUT when I used react-simple-typewriter codes from this [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-typewriter) to my code. It works for only the first word of the word list. But I want that it will continuously run. When I reload it will show the next word from the list. I used to change the only "loop", "loop={0}". But nothing does not work for me. Here is the code sample:

```
   const HeaderHero = () => {
      return (
        <>
          <section className="hero" id="home">
            <div className="container f_flex top">
              <div className="left top">
                <h3>Welcome to my world...</h3>
                <h1>
                  Hi, I'm <span>Samrat Alam</span>
                </h1>
                <h2>
                  a
                  <span>
                    <Typewriter
                      words={[
                        " Developer.",
                        " Learner.",
                        " Coder.",
                        " Self Believer.",
                      ]}
                      loop={0}
                      cursor
                      cursorStyle="|"
                      typeSpeed={70}
                      deleteSpeed={50}
                      delaySpeed={1000}
                    />
                  </span>
                </h2>
    
                <div className="hero_btn d_flex">
                  <div className="col_1">
                    <h4>Find With ME</h4>
                    <button className="btn_shadow">
                      <i className="fab fa-facebook"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button className="btn_shadow">
                      <i className="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button className="btn_shadow">
                      <i className="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </>
      );
    };
    
    export default HeaderHero;
```

Here is the output result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use hooks instead of components. In your case

```
//main file

 import { useTypewriter } from 'react-simple-typewriter';
 import 'react-simple-typewriter/dist/index'

 const HeaderHero = () => {
 const {text} = useTypewriter({
 words: [ " Developer."," Learner."," Coder."," Self 
 Believer.",],
 loop: 0, 
 typeSpeed: 70,
 deleteSpeed: 50,
 delaySpeed: 1000
 })
  return (
    <>
      <section className="hero" id="home">
        <div className="container f_flex top">
          <div className="left top">
            <h3>Welcome to my world...</h3>
            <h1>
              Hi, I'm <span>Samrat Alam</span>
            </h1>
            <h2>
              a
              <span>
                {text}
                <span className="cursor">|</span>
              </span>
            </h2>
```

**you wont get cursor and cursor type when using hooks. But using CSS,  this cursor can be designed.**

```
 //for using the cursor, need this in the CSS file.   

 .cursor {
        animation: blink 1s linear infinite forwards;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the package [react-ts-typewriter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ts-typewriter) `import Typewriter from 'react-ts-typewriter';` and invoking it with:

```
<h1>
<Typewriter loop={true} text="Hello" />
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

As written on the README of react-simple-typewriter to add the cursor using the hook you can import it as a component and place it right after

```
import React from 'react'
import { useTypewriter, Cursor} from 'react-simple-typewriter'

const MyComponent = () => {

  const {text} = useTypewriter({
    words: ['Hello', 'From', 'Typewriter', 'Hook!'],
    loop: {3},
    onLoopDone: () => console.log(`loop completed after 3 runs.`),
  })

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <span>{text}</span>
      <Cursor />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { useTypewriter } from "react-simple-typewriter";

  const [typeEffect]=useTypewriter({
    words:[
      "cat","dog",
    ],
   loop:{},
    typeSpeed:120,
    deleteSpeed:100,

  })
```

Use this typeEffect in text tags. like this:

````
<p style={{color:"#006400",fontSize:"2rem",fontFamily: "'Ubuntu', sans-serif"}}>{typeEffect}</p>```
````

Answer (score 1):

This is my working implementation of react-simple-typewriter using react and nextjs with typescript and tailwind and it also includes the cursor but it should also work with simple react app. You can just remove the theme part if you are not working with dark and light theme modes

```
import { useTheme } from "next-themes";
import React from "react";
import { Cursor, useTypewriter } from "react-simple-typewriter";
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge";



 interface TypeWriterTextPropTypes {
   className?: string;
 }

 const TypeWriterText = (props: TypeWriterTextPropTypes) => {
 const { className } = props;

 const { resolvedTheme } = useTheme();

 const [text, count] = useTypewriter({
    words: [
     "Hello, Typewriter",
     "Typing something good ✨",
     "< Div />",
    ],

  loop: true,
  delaySpeed: 1200,
  typeSpeed: 100,
  deleteSpeed: 70,
});



return (
  <div>
  <h1 className={twMerge("", className)}>
    <span>{text}</span>
    <Cursor
      cursorColor={resolvedTheme === "dark" ? "#48FFF2" : "#1b1b1b"}
    />
   </h1>
  </div>
 );
};
```

export default TypeWriterText;